# Looking for a solution to link checkboxes

Tags: javascript, list, jsp

I need some help because I’m not that experienced with checkboxes.

So, I have a list and each row have a checkbox, by the way this list is auto generated but whatever, what I want is to be able to create some group or a link between some of the checkboxes, that if I check one of them, the others get checked too, of course only the ones linked to that one that I checked.

If it's not possible please let me know.

I hope that you understood what I wrote, and sorry for my bad English. Thank you in advance!

ps: i'm using it in a JSP

Comment: **Show your code** - it helps to understand your problem better, even if your English was bad (which actually isn't, but your way of thinking and explaining is different from what most people are used to, so the code would help to clarify the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it your expect? like follow code

```
 <script>
function f(vobj,vname){
    if(vobj.checked){
        checkoruncheck(vname,'checked');
    }else{
        checkoruncheck(vname,'unchecked');
    }

}
function checkoruncheck(vname,vf){
    var boxs=document.getElementsByName(vname);
    for(i=0;i<boxs.length;i++){
        if(vf==='checked'){  
            boxs[i].checked=true;
        }else{
            boxs[i].checked=false;
        }

    }   
}
</script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onchange="f(this,'checkboxname')"> checkbox A <BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onchange="f(this,'checkboxname')"> checkbox B <BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onchange="f(this,'checkboxname')"> checkbox C <BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onchange="f(this,'checkboxname')"> checkbox D <BR>
```

Comment: I think I got how it works now thanks to your code i'm going to adapt it to my code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
function f(vobj,vname){
    if(vobj.checked){
        checkoruncheck(vname,'checked',vobj.value);
    }else{
        checkoruncheck(vname,'unchecked',vobj.value);
    }

}
function checkoruncheck(vname,vf,value){
    var boxs=document.getElementsByName(vname);
    
    for(i=0;i<boxs.length;i++)
       if( boxs[i].value==value)
        if(vf==='checked') 
            boxs[i].checked=true;
        else 
            boxs[i].checked=false;
    }   

</script>
<span></span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onchange="f(this,'checkboxname')" value="22"> checkbox A <BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onchange="f(this,'checkboxname')" value="22"> checkbox B <BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onchange="f(this,'checkboxname')" value="1"> checkbox C <BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onchange="f(this,'checkboxname')" value="3"> checkbox D <BR>
```

Here is what I was looking for. Thank you guys for the help.